# Java NIO + AES Encryption from Client to Server - ByteBuffer issue

Tags: java, encryption, aes, nio, bytebuffer

I'm quite a newbie regarding encryption and NIO,
I have the following code for client:

```
    String key1 = "1234567812345678";
    byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Encrypted info: " + encrypted);

    String send = encrypted.toString();
    bytebuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
    bytebuf.clear();
    bytebuf.put(send.getBytes());

    bytebuf.flip();

    while(bytebuf.hasRemaining()) {
        nBytes += client.write(bytebuf);
    }
```

and the following code for server:

```
    // Server receives data and decrypts

    SocketChannel socket = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    nBytes = socket.read(buf);
    String data = new String(buf.array()).trim();
    String key1 = "1234567812345678";
    byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Decrypted Info: " + new String(decrypted));
```

When a message is sent from the Client to the Server, "HELLO" for example is encrypted to *[B@34d74aa5* and on the Server side I get *Data packet found as *[B@34d74aa5*.

Till here everything looks fine, but I get the following exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

I suspect that I have some issue with the way the data is coming out of the buffer on the server side?
Any ideas on this?

UPDATE:

**Based on Erickson's answer this is the final solution

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

Client Code:

```
            String key1 = "1234567812345678";
        byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
            byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String text = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Encrypted info: " + text);

        bytebuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
        bytebuf.clear();

        bytebuf.put(text.getBytes());

        bytebuf.flip();

        while(bytebuf.hasRemaining()) {
            nBytes += client.write(bytebuf);
        }
```

Server Code:

```
            LOGGER.info("Confirming write");
        String data = new String(buf.array());

        LOGGER.info("Data packet found as {}", data);

        /*******************************************************/
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        String key1 = "1234567812345678";
        byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

        byte[] encrypted = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Decrypted Info: " + new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` for encryption. You'll get rid of hard-to-understand buffer sizes. (for some reason newbies do like the hard way though)

Comment: I'm using NIO (non-blocking) SocketChannels, I'm not entirely sure but I don't think it's possible to use CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream.

Comment: I have figured out one of the problems was for the encrypted data not arriving to the server correctly, however another problem persists. I will edit and update the question.

Comment: You may find some inspiration from a project that I wrote: [https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/secure-login-file-transfer/](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/secure-login-file-transfer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cipher text, `encrypted`, is a `byte[]`, and invoking `toString()` on an array doesn't render the array content, it returns type (`[B`) and hash code (`@34d74aa5`) information as described by [`Object.toString()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

You can't just use [`new String(encrypted)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) either. When a byte array is decoded to text, the decoder will replace any invalid byte sequences with the replacement character, `\uFFFD` (�). Thus, information is lost and subsequent decryption will fail.

Use an encoding like base-64 to convert byte sequences to printable characters instead. Don't junk up your code with third-party libraries for this; you can use [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte%5B%5D%29)

```
/* Client: */
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String text = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);
…

/* Server: */
byte[] encrypted = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);
byte[] decrypted = Cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
System.out.println(new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You should also be explicit in selecting your mode and padding (like "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding") because there's no guarantee the recipient will use the same provider, or that the same provider will use the same defaults over time. Same goes for specifying character encodings, like UTF-8.

Comment: Great stuff, really helpful. However I'm still stuck while decrypting. I'll update the question with the new info.

Comment: I was missing the IvParameterSpec, forgot to initialize it on the Client side. Without the IvParameterSpec on both sides the decrypt won't work. Any simple explanation for this?

Comment: See my answer... that is how initialization vector's work. They are a random block that initializes the encryption, so it must match on both the encryption and decryption. BTW, you don't need to specify the IV on the client side, since Cipher will generate one for you when you don't specify it. Use `getIV` after `doFinal` to obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the ciphertext, which is a `byte[]`, to a `String` here:

```
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes());
String send = encrypted.toString();
```

This is incorrect. You also cannot do `new String(byte[])` because the `byte[]` is random, not a stream of character data in the platform default encoding assumed by `new String(byte[])`. You should convert the `byte[]` data to a `String` by using a hex or base64 encoding (I recommend [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/)) e.g.

```
hexEncodedCipherText = new String(Hex.encodeHex(binaryCipherText))
```

On the server-side, use the opposite operation to convert the hex or base64 encoded data back to a `byte[]` before decryption e.g.

```
binaryCipherText = Hex.decodeHex(hexEncodedCipherText.toCharArray());
```

UPDATE:

The updated question is not working during decryption because of the incorrect use of the initialization vector. You don't specify an IV during encryption, which means Java will generate a random one. You need to obtain this random IV from the cipher by calling `cipher.getIV()` after the encryption (or specify it explicitly, though generating a random one is more secure). Then, during the decryption, create the `IvParameterSpec` using the IV created during encryption. In addition, you will need to encode/decode the IV in the same manner as the ciphertext, since it is also binary data.

UPDATE 2:

I see you have updated your question with the IV, but you are using a null IV. Generally, this is only "safe" when you have a unique key for every message you send. If your key is fixed or re-used for any significant length of time, you should generate a unique IV for each encryption/decryption. Otherwise, you are leaving yourself open to cryptanalysis based on multiple ciphertexts encrypted with the same key and IV.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your efforts will be more appreciated if you do not copy the substance of an existing answer without contributing any new ideas.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your answer until I had substantially written mine. I'll delete if you wish.

Comment: No problem. Maybe the example of Apache Commons usage is useful.

Comment: Very helpful answer Raman, specially the last part. However since Erickson has answered first I have accepted his answer. Highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The AES scheme is a "block cipher" it works on fixed-size blocks of data. You are creating a "raw" Cipher instance, which will expect you to make sure that every byte array that you pass to the cipher is aligned to the cipher's "native" block length. That's usually not what you want to do.

An additional problem that you are exposing yourself to in using the cipher "raw", although it's not causing an actual error, is that if you were to pass it the same block of data on separate occasions, each time, that block would be encrypted identically, therefore giving an attacker clues as to the structure of the data. Again, that's usually not what you want to do in a practical application.

So usually, you need to specify two extra things: a **padding scheme**, which determines what happens when sections of data are not exactly aligned to a block size, and a **block mode**, which determines what scheme the cipher will use to avoid identical input blocks being encrypted to identical output blocks. The block mode generally needs initialising with a "starting state" called the **initialisation vector** (you could use a default state of "all zero", but that's less secure).

So you need to do two things:

- You need to initialise you cipher with a padding scheme and block
  mode, e.g. "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"
- For additional security, you would also usually set up (and transmit
  before the data) a random initialisation vector. [See this example](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/block_modes_java.shtml) for more
  information.

Comment: Great stuff, I have added the initialization vector with a default state of all zero, I will try and follow the example provided to improve it. Thank you for bringing up the block length issue, that's actually a big problem. +1

Comment: I know what you meant, but the word "default" for the IV is slightly confusing. The default is for Cipher to generate a random one during encryption.

Comment: @Raman Yes, sorry, I should probably have elaborated slightly on that.